# How can I detect text behind a certain word?

Tags: c#, text, bitcoin

my name is Dillion and I am currently working on a project to read values of cryptocurrency basically my program so far goes on google grabs the HTML of [THIS](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera-gx&hs=yPs&sxsrf=ALeKk0205SPDb6fcqea6Uj5cJonUrDy-Pg%3A1609942273376&ei=AcX1X5i2Fq2g5wLr8bDgAg&q=bitcoin+price&oq=bitcoin+price&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIQCAAQsQMQgwEQyQMQFBCHAjIICAAQsQMQgwEyDQgAELEDEIMBEBQQhwIyCAgAELEDEIMBMggIABCxAxCDATIICAAQsQMQgwEyCAgAELEDEIMBMgIIADIICAAQsQMQgwEyAggAOgQIABBHOgQIIxAnOgoIABCxAxCDARBDUN8yWNU4YO05aABwAngAgAFUiAHRA5IBATeYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjYusCqvofuAhUt0FkKHes4DCwQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) link and searches for the text "United States Dollar". I have had it print out the HTML and I have searched for "united states dollar" and in the same string thing this pops up "34,859.30 United States Dollar". Since the value of Bitcoin is always changing I can't just search for "34,859.30 United States Dollar" and print it out because it is always changing. Can anyone help me learn how to search text behind the "United States Dollar" so i can also include the value of bitcoin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the HTML is in a string variable called str:

```
int startingLocation = str.IndexOf("United States Dollar");
string amount = str.Substring(startingLocation - 10).Trim();
```

This only works if the string behind the text is 10 characters, which in your example it is. IndexOf() returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified string. Trim() removes unnecessary whitespace.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, I would recommend using something like beautifulsoup in python.

A better suggestion though, would be to use an API for that purpose such as:
https://www.coindesk.com/coindesk-api